# What is a good SDK for GIS on Windows Mobile?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, dictionary, gis

I'm looking for suggestions for a GIS SDK on windows mobile. It needs to be able to display ESRI Shapefiles efficiently.

Comment: If your only requirement is loading and displaying a shapefile then shapelib and a small custom drawing routine are everything you need.

Comment: Ideally we'd like one that we can perform spatial queries on , etc. As much as a full GIS as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the Esri one? Or are you talking older Windows mobile?

http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/smartphones/index.html

Comment: I'm sorry I should have mentioned that it needs to be Windows Mobile 6 compatible (otherwise a good suggestion).

Answer (score 1):

Esri also has the ArcGIS Mobile SDK for Windows Mobile 5 and 6:
http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgismobile/index.html